# Is there an equivalent PostgresSQL window function (or alternate procedure) for the aggregate function bool_or()?

Tags: postgresql

Given the following data:

```
select a,b from newtable;
 a | b
---+---
 a | f
 a | f
 a | f
 b | f
 b | f
 b | t
(6 rows)
```

The statement

```
select a, bool_or(b) from newtable group by a;
 a | bool_or
---+---------
 a | f
 b | t
```

will produce a single row per distinct value (as expected from an aggregate function).

I was looking for an equivalent [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-window.html) but seems that there is no such function in PostgreSQL. Is there any way to get the same result? Just to be clear I was looking for this result:

```
 a | bool_or
---+---------
 a | f
 a | f
 a | f
 b | t
 b | t
 b | t
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the `bool_or()` is not explicitly listed in the [PostgreSQL documentation page for window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-window.html) you can still use [aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-aggregate.html) like `bool_or()` or any built-in function over windows.

It says so in the window function documentation:

> any built-in or user-defined general-purpose or statistical aggregate
>   can be used as a window function

So to get the desired result use:

```
select a, bool_or(b) over w from newtable window w as (partition by a) ;
 a | bool_or
---+---------
 a | f
 a | f
 a | f
 b | t
 b | t
 b | t
(6 rows)
```